# Does stopping azure function app terminates executing timer trigger function or lets it complete its run and not reschedule after

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, timer-trigger

I have an azure function app containing around 10 timer triggered functions. Each function has its own interval which differs from other functions.

In order to redeploy the function app, i want to make sure that the currently executing functions are not affected.

I am stopping my function app in the azure pipeline before deploying the function app but want to know if it will terminate the currently running function runs or it will complete the current execution of each function and then not reschedule for next run?

Slots will also have the same problem when we will do swap slot.

What would be the best possible solution in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding and investigation. Stopping the function app will terminate all running processes. But a cancellation token can be used to handle the termination process gracefully